# Office Add-In SSO with an AAD v1 app registration

Tags: azure-active-directory, access-token, sharepoint-online, office-addins

I am developing a office add-in.
This office Add-In is supposed to retrieve the term store from SharePoint.
By following this tutorial: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/create-sso-office-add-ins-aspnet 
I managed to get an access token to be used for Graph api. However the Graph does not expose any way of getting the term store. Is there a way we can generate an access token to be used with SharePoint and maintain the SSO?
It might be possible by registering an Azure AD v1 app but I could not find any documentation describing that.

Answer (score 4):

I have a similar requirement, but in my research I wasn't able to find a good solution for this scenario.

I think it is probably possible to use a provider hosted SharePoint add-in. And then use the Authorization Code flow for obtaining an access token. Since the SharePoint add-in is trusted it will not require user login.

Of course this does mean the add-in needs to be deployed in SharePoint. If your Office add-in is distributed through the store this isn't really a great solution.

Hopefully there are other ways of achieving the same.

Answer (score 3):

You could call SharePoint Online APIs (via REST or CSOM) with Azure Active Directory Apps. To call APIs secured by Azure AD, your app must acquire an access token from Azure Active Directory.

Please first refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-integrating-applications) for integrating applications with Azure Active Directory. Then use [Azure Active Directory Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-libraries) Library (ADAL) to easily authenticate users to cloud or on-premises Active Directory (AD), and obtain access tokens for securing API calls.

Comment: Fetching the term store using the REST Api seems very difficult. There is the TaxonomyInternalService.json that can be called, but this one requires some authentication cookies (i believe the FedAuth cookie for SharePoint Online). This might work well for SharePoint hosted apps, but not provider hosted apps. The CSOM approach seems to work very well though.

Comment: For the time being this is what I'm going for (ADAL) even though it requires user interaction.